# Adding multiple products to productlist for queryProductDetailsAsync in android billing 5.0.0

Tags: java, android, play-billing-library

In the old android billing implementation you would build an sku list to query products:

```
List<String> skuList = new ArrayList<>();
        skuList.add(SKU_POTION);
        skuList.add(SKU_SWORD);
        skuList.add(SKU_BOW);
        SkuDetailsParams.Builder params = SkuDetailsParams.newBuilder();
        params.setSkusList(skuList).setType(BillingClient.SkuType.INAPP);
```

The new billing implementation is more involved, and appears to limit you to adding just one product to a query list:

```
ImmutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = ImmutableList.from(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(SKU_POTION)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build());
    
            QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                    .setProductList(productList)
                    .build();
    
            billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
            params,
            new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
                public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && productDetailsList != null) {
                        for (ProductDetails skuDetails : productDetailsList) {                    
                            mProductDetailsMap.put(skuDetails.getProductId(), skuDetails);                           
                        }
                    }
                   
                }
            }
    );
```

It makes you build the productList for the productDetailsList for the mProductDetailsMap that's needed to start the purchase flow:

```
puchasestring=SKU_POTION;
initiatePurchaseFlow(mProductDetailsMap.get(puchasestring));
```

How would I add multiple products to the productList that begins the implementation? I don't want to have to repeat the entire code segment for each item to add to the mProductDetailsMap, which is the Primitive Pete method I'm using for now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For multiple products:

```
ImmutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productList = ImmutableList.from(
QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(SKU_POTION)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build(),
QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(SKU_SWORD)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build(),
QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId(SKU_BOW)
                    .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                    .build());
```

Comment: Why do product types need to be the same? Why I can't query to both in apps and subs with a single query

Answer (score 20):

You don't actually have to use an `ImmutableList`. The [official examples](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5#showing-products) use an `ImmutableList` for some reason to build the query, but it isn't necessary. The [`setProductList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/QueryProductDetailsParams.Builder) method just takes `List<Product>` as its input, so you could just do something like this:

```java
List<String> skuList = Arrays.asList(SKU_POTION, SKU_SWORD, SKU_BOW);

ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String sku : skuList) {
    productList.add(
        Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId(sku)
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build()
    );
}

QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList)
        .build();

billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(params, new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
    public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
        // handle response
    }
}
```

Anything that implements the `List` interface will work - `ArrayList`, `ImmutableList`, etc...

**UPDATE**

If you want to query a mix of INAPP and SUBS types, you can't do this with a single call. However, you can use flows to combine the two async calls and run them at the same time (faster than running them one-at-a-time and easier to deal with the results)

First, make a helper function to return a flow for each call to `queryProductDetails` (this requires the billing `-ktx` extension in gradle)

```kotlin
private fun getDetailsFlow(productIds: List<String>, type: String) : Flow<List<ProductDetails>> {

    val productList = productIds.map { productId ->
        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId(productId)
            .setProductType(type)
            .build()
    }

    val params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder().setProductList(productList).build()

    return flow {
        emit(billingClient?.queryProductDetails(params))
    }.map { result ->
        result?.productDetailsList ?: emptyList()
    }
}
```

Then zip together two flows to get a single list of products as a result.

```kotlin
fun queryProductDetails() {

    val inAppFlow = getDetailsFlow(listOf(Product.GOLD, Product.SILVER), BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
    val subsFlow = getDetailsFlow(listOf(Product.UNLIMITED), BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)

    val allDetailsFlow = inAppFlow.zip(subsFlow) { inAppResult, subsResult ->
        return@zip inAppResult + subsResult
    }

    scope.launch {
        allDetailsFlow.collect { productList ->
            // handle the unified list of all products, subscription and in-app
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Great answer just please note that `BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS` is actually `BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP` if you would like to query in app purchase products and not subscirptions.

Comment: I was facing this same issue. But your answer help me a lot. Great answer

Comment: I have a prod app working and I was trying to migrate so, only issue I was facing is trying to query billing client with mix of SUB and IAP. So annoying. Thank you.