# How to get multiple product details from Google Play Billing 5?

Tags: android, google-play, play-billing-library

How do you query a list of products from google play billing 5?

From https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/integrate#java, we query the details of a single product by passing the name of the product to `setProductId`,

```
QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams =
    QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(
            ImmutableList.of(
                Product.newBuilder()
                    .setProductId("product_id_example")
                    .setProductType(ProductType.SUBS)
                    .build()))
        .build();

billingClient.queryProductDetailsAsync(
    queryProductDetailsParams,
    new ProductDetailsResponseListener() {
        public void onProductDetailsResponse(BillingResult billingResult,
                List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList) {
            // check billingResult
            // process returned productDetailsList
        }
    }
)
```

But that only gets a single product, thus when you try to print out `List<ProductDetails> productDetailsList` there is only one. So how do you pass in multiple products?

As far as I am aware `.setProductId("product_id_example")` only takes a string and not a list.

Answer (score 5):

The [official examples](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/migrate-gpblv5#showing-products) use an `ImmutableList` for some reason to build the query, but you don't actually need to use that. The [`setProductList`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/QueryProductDetailsParams.Builder) method just takes `List<Product>` as its input, it does not require `ImmutableList`.

You could use something like this (API 24+ to use `stream()`):

```java
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1","2","3"); // your product IDs

List<Product> productList = ids.stream().map( productId -> 
    Product.newBuilder()
           .setProductId(productId)
           .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
           .build()
).collect(Collectors.toList());

QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList)
        .build();
```

If you have API < 24, you could just make an ArrayList instead.

```java
List<String> ids = Arrays.asList("1","2","3"); // your product IDs

ArrayList<Product> productList = new ArrayList<>();
for(String productId : ids) {
    productList.add(
        Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId(productId)
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build()
    );
}

QueryProductDetailsParams params = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
        .setProductList(productList)
        .build();
```

I suspect they wrote the example in Kotlin (using `listOf`), and automatically converted it to Java (somehow giving us `ImmutableList.of`)...

Answer (score 3):

Looks like a good answer can be found here: [Adding multiple products to productlist for queryProductDetailsAsync in android billing 5.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72396628/adding-multiple-products-to-productlist-for-queryproductdetailsasync-in-android)

But I'll provide some comments below:

To add additional products we need to have the products in the `immutableList`, so without a for-loop we can just have:

```
QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductList(
                        ImmutableList.of(
                                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                        .setProductId("Product1")
                                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                        .build(),
                                QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
                                        .setProductId("Product2")
                                        .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
                                        .build()
                )).build();
```

However, that isn't suitable if your products need to be populated dynamically. This means we need to dynamically populate the items within the `ImmutableList`. You'll notice that the `add` method for `ImmutableList` is deprecated so the `add` method does nothing.

As a work around, I created an `ArrayList`, populate the products into the `ArrayList` and then cast it to an `ImmutableList`

```
ImmutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> productsList = ImmutableList.of();
ArrayList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> products = new ArrayList();
for (String productId : productIds ) {
    products.add(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId(productId)
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.INAPP)
            .build());
}

productsList = ImmutableList.copyOf(products);

QueryProductDetailsParams queryProductDetailsParams = QueryProductDetailsParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductList(productsList).build();
```

Comment: I noticed that we cant query `ProductType.INAPP` and `ProductType.SUBS` together in single query, is there a way to get both in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

You just use MutableList to make it easy

```
val productList : MutableList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product> = arrayListOf()
for (product in LIST_OF_PRODUCTS) {
    productList.add(
        QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
            .setProductId(product)
            .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
            .build()
    )
}
```

```
private val LIST_OF_PRODUCTS = listOf(
            "basic_subscription",
            "premium_subscription"
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

To query a list of products from Google Play Billing Library version 5 (or later), you typically use the `QueryProductDetailsParams` method. Here's a general overview of how you can do this:

```
val productList = ArrayList<QueryProductDetailsParams.Product>()
productList.add(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
    .setProductId(Constants.BASE_PLAN)
    .setProductType(SUBS)
    .build()
)

productList.add(QueryProductDetailsParams.Product.newBuilder()
    .setProductId(Constants.STANDER_PLAN)
    .setProductType(SUBS)
    .build()
)
```